# Accessing controller variable from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am coding an AngularJS application.
I need to load data from a SQLite3 database. The architecture I'm using for this is: I have a Node.js server using express which communicates with the angular.js application through socket.io. So, I make a petition from the client to get info from the database, the server gathers that info and sends it back to the client.

Here I'm trying to initialize an array of objects: `main.meds` (using angular.js routeProvider, I have referenced 'MainCtrl' as 'main'):

```
angular.module('medsOrmApp').controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.socket = io();
  this.meds = [];

  this.socket.emit('loadMeds', 'gimme the list !');
  this.socket.on('medsResponse', function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var tmp = {};
      tmp.id = data[i].ID_MEDICAMENTO;
      tmp.nombre = data[i].NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO;
      tmp.cantidad = data[i].CANTIDAD_DISPONIBLE;
      tmp.lab = data[i].LABORATORIO;
      meds.push(tmp); // ERROR: 'meds' is not defined
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that I can't access 'meds' from inside the anonymous function. I've tried with `meds` and `this.meds` without success.

Comment: try to save your this in another variable (var that = this for example) and then use that.meds in the anonymous function

Comment: It worked with the `var that = this` at the beginning of the controller ! Thank you very much, Julien.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work if you used `$scope`?

```
angular.module('medsOrmApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  this.socket = io();
  this.meds = [];

  this.socket.emit('loadMeds', 'gimme the list !');
  this.socket.on('medsResponse', function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var tmp = {};
      tmp.id = data[i].ID_MEDICAMENTO;
      tmp.nombre = data[i].NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO;
      tmp.cantidad = data[i].CANTIDAD_DISPONIBLE;
      tmp.lab = data[i].LABORATORIO;
      this.meds.push(tmp); // ERROR: 'meds' is not defined
    }
  });
});
```

edit: what about adding `this.meds.push`?

Comment: it wotks it seems that he wants to use "controller as" syntax

Comment: yes, I've generated the project with yeoman and it's configured that way, no need to switch to the `$scope` syntax